# Custom Installer Class

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, installation

I'm working on a project which needs some third party components prequisites to be installed before installing my .NET Application. Can someone tell me how to do it ?? I'm using .NET prequisites components to install the components like (.NET Framework 3.5,Windows installer 3.1,Crystal Reports) but what if i have some third party components which is not listed in prequisite lists ... Please let me know how can i achieve this ??

Comment: Care to share some information regarding the nature of your top secret third party components and what they might need to do as part of their installation process? It might help people to provide more relevant answers.

Comment: Use a deployment tool capable of deploying your prerequisites. [**Here is a description of various tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941).

Answer (score 1):

create [custom installer](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/0df20605-b457-42d6-b63c-341a3824474a.htm) and do in installer class what you want

Comment: yes i'm using the custom installer class but i want to know if some component fails to install then how can i rollback the installation. I have rollback method but its not working .. can you please let me know how can i achieve it ...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the 3rd party components you refer to would be distributed via a Merge Module.  Check and see if they are, then you can simply include them with your installer.